# Update may be too big for my hard drive

Tags: downloads

The software updater says it will download 1027 MB. I don't think I have that much room on my hard drive. But I assume that much of it is simply duplicate with the operating system and will just replace what I have there. In other words, I assume this download is the new version of Ubuntu. But I've been reluctant to download. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You should either try to free up space or add new hard drive. With free space of less than 1GB, what can you do with the computer anyway?